# MDX, first SUM then AVERAGE

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a fact model that contains the following data:

```
WorkOrderNumber | WorkOrderLineNumber | Cost
```

So I have a dimension WorkOrder:

```
[WorkOrder].[WorkOrderNumber]
[WorkOrder].[WorkOrderLineNumber]
```

And a Measure group with the following Measure:

```
[Measures].[Cost]
```

I am trying to create a calculate measure:

```
[Measures].[Average WorkOrder Cost]
```

This must be calculated by Summing up the values per Work Order and afterwards taking an average of all these sums per workorders.

However I can not seem to get it working.

```
CASE WHEN [WorkOrder].[WorkOrder].CurrentMember = [WorkOrder].[WorkOrder].[All] 
THEN 
  /* the work order is not selected -> AVG*/ 
  DIVIDE(SUM(),[Measures].[Cost]), Count()) )) 
ELSE 
  /* the Work Order is selected -> SUM*/ 
  SUM([Measures].[Cost]) 
END
```

Comment: The approach I am trying is wrong, however I do not know how to handle it better. What I currently Have: CASE WHEN 
    [WorkOrder].[WorkOrder].CurrentMember = [WorkOrder].[WorkOrder].[All]
THEN 
    /* the work order is not selected -> AVG*/
    DIVIDE(SUM(),[Measures].[Cost]),
        Count())
    ))
ELSE
    /* the Work Order is selected -> SUM*/
    SUM([Measures].[Cost])
END This approach is wrong. I first see if the end user has selected all work orders. if so I can just sum. else I dont know :( However I can not just take the sum because end user could have selected 2 work orders..

Comment: @OverflowStack Ok, few quick questions..Why are you taking an average?? Isn't the requirement just to sum up the cost for the selected work orders selected by the user? Secondly, is there any significance of  `WorkOrderLineNumber` in the context of the current question, or is it just about WorkOrderNumber?

Comment: I want to have an average cost price per workorder. this means summing up the costs on the workorder lines and divide this by the number of workorders. the significance of work order line number... it is the lowest level of detail. However maybe not needed to come to a solution. it is to make clear you can not just add the sum of the workorderlines and divide by the number of workorderlines. The average needs to be calculated a level higer. on the workorder level.  more thinking about it. I suppose having the denominator of my divide as the number of selected workorder I also get there..

Comment: Perhaps you should add a Count column to your Fact, with a value of 1 for each record. Then your calculated measure could just be a ratio of the SUM of the cost divided by the SUM of the Count.

Comment: You could be like Adventure Works and add a DistinctCount measure on the WorkOrderNumber and then use that as the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of taking an average per sales order using the Adventure Works cube. You could replace with your [Cost] and [WorkOrderNumber]...

```
with member [CalculatedAvg] as 
    AVG([Internet Sales Order Details].[Sales Order Number].[Sales Order Number], [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
    , FORMAT_STRING = "$#,##0.00"

select
    { 
        [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], 
        [Measures].[Internet Order Count], 
        [Measures].[Internet Average Sales Amount],
        [CalculatedAvg] 
    } on 0,
    [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].members on 1
from
    [Direct Sales]
```

for example...

```
AVG([WorkOrder].[WorkOrderNumber].[WorkOrderNumber], [Measures].[Cost])
```

Comment: why not use the function `AVG`?